How come the android face detection detects my face on the phone but the system server doesn't detect it?
I am trying to get face recognition to work on this android app I am making. On my phone it says the face has been detected but the system_server says it has not been detected.
Logcat messages I get on Android Studio
I am making this making this android app that needs to communicate with a laravel website and authenticate users with their faces. It is supposed to send this data to a MySQL server on the laravel website and verify if their face exists and if there is no image it saves their face and if it's not the same they can't clock in but the app can't seem to detect my face on the backend. I am mlkit face detection on android and then retrofit to send the requests to the laravel website and then face++ API to check if the faces match. But when I try and use my face it says face detected and doesn't do anything after and then the app says it's taking too long to respond. So I checked the logs on Android Studio and saw that the "SmartStayController" is saying faceDetected:false and I'm not sure that means or how to fix it.
package com.example.clockinclockout

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetection
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetectorOptions
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class FaceRecognitionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var previewView: PreviewView
    private lateinit var captureButton: Button
    private lateinit var imageCapture: ImageCapture
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    private var companyId: Int = 0
    private var employeeId: Int = 0

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1001
        private const val TAG = "FaceRecognitionActivity"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_face_recognition)

        companyId = intent.getIntExtra("companyId", 0)
        employeeId = intent.getIntExtra("employeeId", 0)

        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView)
        captureButton = findViewById(R.id.captureButton)

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
        } else {
            startCamera()
        }

        captureButton.setOnClickListener {
            capturePhoto()
        }
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
            }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA

            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun capturePhoto() {
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        imageCapture.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
                val bitmap = imageProxyToBitmap(imageProxy)
                imageProxy.close()

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    processFace(bitmap)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Capture failed: ${exception.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun imageProxyToBitmap(imageProxy: ImageProxy): Bitmap? {
        val buffer = imageProxy.planes[0].buffer
        val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
        buffer.get(bytes)
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
    }

    private fun processFace(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        val image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0)
        val detector = FaceDetection.getClient(
            FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_FAST)
                .setLandmarkMode(FaceDetectorOptions.LANDMARK_MODE_NONE)
                .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_NONE)
                .build()
        )

        detector.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
                if (faces.isNotEmpty()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Face detected")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Face detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    checkFaceExists(companyId, employeeId, bitmap)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No face detected")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No face detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {e ->
                Log.e(TAG, "Face detection failed: ${e.message}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to process face: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }

    private fun checkFaceExists(companyId: Int, employeeId: Int, bitmap: Bitmap) {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://9820-41-80-113-159.ngrok-free.app/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val api = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
        val imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

        val faceRequest = FaceRequest(companyId, employeeId, imageBytes)

        api.verifyFace(faceRequest).enqueue(object : Callback<VerifyFaceResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<VerifyFaceResponse>, response: Response<VerifyFaceResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val verifyResponse = response.body()
                    if (verifyResponse != null && verifyResponse.success) {
                        clockInUser(companyId, employeeId, imageBytes)
                    } else {
                        saveFace(companyId, employeeId, imageBytes)
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Error: ${response.message()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<VerifyFaceResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Network error: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun saveFace(companyId: Int, employeeId: Int, imageBytes: ByteArray) {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://9820-41-80-113-159.ngrok-free.app/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val api = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        val faceRequest = FaceRequest(companyId, employeeId, imageBytes)

        api.saveFace(faceRequest).enqueue(object : Callback<SaveFaceResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<SaveFaceResponse>, response: Response<SaveFaceResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val saveResponse = response.body()
                    if (saveResponse != null && saveResponse.success) {
                        clockInUser(companyId, employeeId, imageBytes)
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Failed to save face", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Error: ${response.message()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SaveFaceResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Network error: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun clockInUser(companyId: Int, employeeId: Int, imageBytes: ByteArray) {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://9820-41-80-113-159.ngrok-free.app/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val api = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        val clockInRequest = ClockInRequest(companyId, employeeId, imageBytes)

        api.clockIn(clockInRequest).enqueue(object : Callback<ClockInResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ClockInResponse>, response: Response<ClockInResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val clockInResponse = response.body()
                    if (clockInResponse != null && clockInResponse.success) {
                        startActivity(Intent(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, SuccessActivity::class.java))
                        finish()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Failed to clock in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Error: ${response.message()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ClockInResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@FaceRecognitionActivity, "Network error: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

public function verifyFace(Request $request)
    {
        $employee = Employee::where('Company_ID', $request->companyId)
            ->where('Employee_ID', $request->employeeId)
            ->first();

        if ($employee && $employee->Image) {
            $savedImage = base64_decode($employee->Image);
            $currentImage = base64_decode($request->image);

            $facesMatch = $this->compareFaces($savedImage, $currentImage);

            return response()->json(['success' => $facesMatch]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['success' => false]);
        }
    }

    public function saveFace(Request $request)
    {
        $employee = Employee::where('Company_ID', $request->companyId)
            ->where('Employee_ID', $request->employeeId)
            ->first();

        if ($employee) {
            $employee->Image = base64_encode($request->image);
            $employee->save();

            return response()->json(['success' => true]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['success' => false]);
        }
    }

    private function compareFaces($image1, $image2)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post('https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/compare', [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'api_key',
                    'contents' => $this->facePlusPlusApiKey
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'api_secret',
                    'contents' => $this->facePlusPlusApiSecret
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'image_base64_1',
                    'contents' => base64_encode($image1)
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'image_base64_2',
                    'contents' => base64_encode($image2)
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $result = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        return isset($result['confidence']) && $result['confidence'] > 80;
    }

